# How to connect to proxy in android

Tags: java, android, kotlin

I need your help about connecting to proxy. I have some information like port, address, username and password and the point is I have no url. I just need to connnect to this proxy. All examples I saw there was an url and then they created a okHttpClient and set the proxy to it.
What should I do?

Comment: You should tell us what you should do with the proxy as soon as you 'just connected' to it.

Comment: A proxy URL is simply `http://address:port` or if the proxy uses HTTPS the same with `https://`. username and password is usually provided separately.